# Falla al transferir archivos desde mi máquina virtual a un servidor de backups mediante scp

Tags: linux

Estoy tratando de enviar un archivo de nombre chatty.txt (que realmente es un archivo vacío) desde mi máquina virtual (192.168.99.30/24)a un servidor de backups(192.168.101.17/24). Entre ambos ya existe ping.

El username del servidor de backups es "backup", y quiero que el archivo se copie en el directorio "diario".

El comando que estoy usando es el siguiente:

scp chatty.txt backup@192.168.101.17:/u07/diario

Pero simplemente obtengo lo siguiente:

ssh: connect to host 192.168.101.17 port 22: Connection timed out lost connection

Alguna sugerencia por favor. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: `ssh -vvv backup@192.168.101.17` te da info de debug para ver si es el tunel ssh, asegurate que el puerto 22 este abierto, el servicio ssh este funcionando, el user backup tenga permiso de conectar por ssh y que todo esto sea accesible entre las 2 subredes ( 192.168.99.xxx y 192.168.101.xxx )

Comment: gracias, lo probaré y comentaré como me fue.